# Is space expanding?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, space-expansion

Is the observed stretching of the SNIa lightcurves, ie the delaying of the emitted photons at reception, evidence that space is expanding or should this be explained otherwise and how?

Comment: Could you link to the observations you mention?

Answer (score 3):

There is no yes/no answer to this. The equations used in general relativity to describe this do not clearly map onto English statements like "space is expanding" or "space is not expanding."